# Migrating from iptables to firewalld : commenting rules

Tags: linux, iptables, firewalld

I'm migrating from iptables to firewalld, using Centos 7.
In the old times, I used to write the (permament) iptables rules in the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` , which also served to place comments prepended by `#` (to remind us why we restricted this or that ip, etc).

Now, it seems that the current (permanent) configuration is read from `/etc/firewalld/` files (especially `/etc/firewalld/zones/*.xml`). I guess I could add xml comments there, but it seems the good practice is not to edit those files directly but via `firewall-cmd` (no?).

Hence, I'm not sure which is the standard or recommended way to add comments to the rules.

Any suggestions?

Edited: For the record, I've verified that xml comments do not survive `firewall-cmd` modifications.

Comment: As a general rule, you don't. What are you trying to accomplish with comments? There may be a better way to reach the end goal, whatever it is.

Comment: I gave an example: I block an ip (place it inside a drop zone) and I want to remind me why. Also, I add acces to a non-standard tcp port that I use for a test service, etc. The general point is maintenance.

Comment: OK, that does make sense. Though such comments are probably better suited for your configuration management system.

Comment: another example: allow users to see current firewall rules on a server with comments - if on the server they can easily see settings and related comments instead of having to go someplace else to get that info (useful for devs and devops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thinking it over, I'm finding this `firewalld-cmd` thing slightly silly. After all, XML configuration files are human editable. It makes little sense to me, having to learn an extra layer of commands (well, one command, but with [tons of arguments](http://www.firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html)) only to edit some simple and neat XML files (*).

I fell slightly stupid typing

`firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=work --add-port=445/tcp`

just for addding the following line to `/etc/firewalld/zones/work.xml`

`<port protocol="tcp" port="445"/>`

Hence, at least for now, and considering that the XML elements don't include comment attributes (there are [some](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/194) [requests](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/269) in that direction) I'm leaning towards the following strategy: just forget about  `firewalld-cmd` (perhaps even delete it), edit the XML files yourself, and add XML comments freely.

(*) It's true that `firewalld-cmd` allows also to add dynamic (non permanent) rules. But I'd bet that that is not a very frequent scenario.

Comment: you could also just stick to iptables by [removing firewalld and installing iptables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-firewalld-to-iptables-on-centos-7)

Comment: @user12345 Sure. I just try to become familiar with these new things, especially if they became more or less standard.

Answer (score 2):

As of 10/2022, I think `firewalld` use sufficiently widespread that **ease of annotating rules either from `firewall-cmd` or from `firewall-config` is very important**, for reasons discussed in the OP.

Suggestions that we document rules in a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), via `firewall-cmd --direct`, via *ipsets*, or edit zone files manually, all complicate management and defeat a purpose of `firewalld`, that of [making firewall configuration more transparent](https://firewalld.org/).

Therefore, until `firewall-cmd --comment` becomes available, I will annotate my rules via the `log prefix` option to `firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule`.  For example,

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family=ipv4 source address=192.168.103.224 reject log prefix='Onsite NIDS 1'"
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family=ipv4 source address=192.168.103.225 reject log prefix='Onsite NIDS 2'"
```

The resulting annotation appears in my system log as a side-effect, but now output of `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` is self-documenting:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens160
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 1515/tcp 1514/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.103.224" log prefix="Onsite NIDS 1" reject
        rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.103.225" log prefix="Onsite NIDS 2" reject
```

The comment is also recorded in my zone file as:

```
# cat /etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="http"/>
  <service name="https"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="1515"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="1514"/>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="192.168.103.224"/>
    <log prefix="Onsite NIDS 1"/>
    <reject/>
  </rule>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="192.168.103.225"/>
    <log prefix="Onsite NIDS 2"/>
    <reject/>
  </rule>
</zone>
```

I realize that **even this approach overly complicates configuration** by introducing *rich rules,* but believe the benefit in annotation worthwhile for now.

Comment: If one uses the "log prefix" workaround as shown above, is there a potential concern for performance? Wondering if I were to use this for opening a port on something like a home/remote server that's maintaining an active connection, if the system would be generating more log statements about the connection. Probably wouldn't be a big deal for a file server but something like a game server or a mumble server where there are long-ish active connections even with a small number of users (<5), I'm not sure. Any clues?

Comment: @zpangwin: Especially when relevant logs are written to a disk, there can be performance concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Although in the firewall-cmd man page, there is a section on Direct Options, that allow you to give parameters, so you could do something like:

`firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule <table> <chain> <priority> <args> -c <some comment>`

Although, as Michael Hampton said, probably not the best thing.